# Uso de "global" com mysqli deixa a conexão aberta?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, global

Nesta forma de acesso ao banco com `mysqli` fiquei na dúvida se são abertas duas conexões, e se, depois de fechar a do `$stmt`, se ainda fica uma conexão sempre aberta.

O uso é basicamente este:

```
$host = "mysql.host.com.br";
$db = "dbname";
$user = "user";
$passw = "passw";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $dbname, $user, $passw);

GLOBAL $mysqli;
```

Então para usar faz:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(SELECT...);
$stmt = execute();
...
$stmt->close();
```

Então a primeira dúvida é se no caso ficam abertas duas conexões, uma que é usada na *query* com `$stmt`, e a outra que fica aberta (`$mysqli`) esperando algum outro *request* acontecer.

Sendo apenas uma, a conexão da variável `$mysqli` vai ficar aberta até o limite do *timeout*, ou se quando fecha com `$stmt` ela fecha também a global (`$mysqli`)?

Comment: Global é no escopo do script, deixa de existir ao final. PHP não tem variáveis de sessão,  e muito menos de aplicação (o que eu sinto uma falta danada, por sinal). Seria legal vc explicar melhor esse "deixa conexão aberta". Qualquer conexão fica aberta por um tempo, enquanto a variável estiver no escopo. O Global só muda a visibilidade da variável justamente em relação ao escopo, o resto é consequência.

Comment: como você está montando isso, é tudo com `include`? isso vai depender da organização, se você colocar uma pagina que inclui essa conexão temos apenas 1 conexão aberta.

Comment: É isso mesmo @VirgilioNovic, achei que abria outra quando faz `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare`, valeu pelo complemento. abs

Comment: Então @Bacco eu fiquei na dúvida se quando fechava com `$stmt->close()` fechava também a global do $mysqli, mas pela resposta do @Maniero, e pensando melhor agora, parece meio óbvio que não né hehe. Valeu a força man, desde sempre! abs

Comment: @gustavox isso que vc acaba de dizer não tem relação com o titulo da pergunta e nem do escopo que eu comentei. Esse close ai é método do statement, não da conexão. O statement aberto permite você ir avançando nos registros, exeutar passos, até que fechado. Aí ele libera os recursos daquele statement (que são relacionados à conexão, mas são coisas separadas). Seria legal você dar uma revisada no manual para entender a classe que é retornada pelo prepare

Comment: Pois é @Bacco, é que vocês estão overating o meu entendimento da matéria rsrs Agora que eu entendi que "O statement aberto permite você ir avançando nos registros, exeutar passos, até que fechado" e que isso não afeta a conexão que foi aberta. Acho que vcs estão pressupondo que eu deveria saber disso, mas eu não sabia.

Comment: @gustavox o meu pressuposto com base no comment era de vc não saber, e por isso que eu comentei o que era :D

Comment: A página principal do statement nao ajuda muito, mas os links dos métodos levam para mais detalhes https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php

Comment: Não confundir com isso aqui, que eu realmente não recomendo usar sem uma razão MUITO especial (nunca experimentei situação real em que fosse benéfico, muito pelo contrário) https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta não faz sentido, ela pressupõe que está abrindo duas conexões quando claramente o código mostra que só uma está sendo aberta.

O segundo código está usando a conexão já aberta, não está abrindo uma nova. E o fechamento que ocorre ali é da *query* e não da conexão, a conexão está suportada pela variável `$mysqli`, e o que está fechando é a variável `$stmt` que suporta só a *query*. Somente quando fizer `$mysqli->close()` é que a conexão será fechada (ou se o *script* encerrar, que se for ver o contexto todo do código parece que é quando esta conexão será fechada).

Comment: Sentido faz, tanto que você respondeu o que eu queria saber. Vide "Então a primeira dúvida é se no caso ficam abertas duas conexões". De qualquer forma valeu pela resposta mega ultra rápida! :) abs